# about forward propagation and backward propagation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

[image]

I would need a piece of help please : given the simple neuronal network that is outlined in the picture,

I would have 2 questions :

1. how shall I implement in Python the derivatives during the back-propagation ?
2. how the backward propagation informs the forward propagation ?

And, assuming that I do have a network such as :

```
X0 = X
G0 = np.matmul(W0,X0) + B0
H0 = unit_activation(G0)
X1 = H0
G1 = np.matmul(W1,X1) + B1
H1 = unit_activation(G1)
X2 = G1
G2 = np.matmul(W2,X2) + B2
H2 = tanh_activation(G2)
Yhat = H2
```

how shall I write the back-propagation in python ?

Comment: 1.  Although you can implement back-prop yourself from scratch, you should consider using a framework like Tensorflow that contains the derivative calculation, etc. for back prop.   2.  Backward propagation computes the derivatives of loss w.r.t. the neural net variables, and uses those in turn to minimize loss by changing the variables; this has the effect of changing how forward-propagation works.   Hopefully, the result of this is to find a set of variables that minimizes the loss.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mark. I have been asked to implement the back-propagation by myself, and I do not know if I shall compute the derivatives per neuron in the layer, or per layer . On the other hand, would you let me know : after I compute the derivatives in order to update the weights, how shall I inform the forward-propagation about the updated weights ? Thanks again !

Comment: I understand.   So, suppose in your network you have variables V = { v0, ..., vN-1 }.   The first step, as you've identified, is to find the value of the derivative of loss w.r.t. each of the variables.   Suppose the derivative values are D = { d0,  ..., dN-1 }.   Then, what you will do is to update each variable vI with the assignment "vI = vI - dI * alpha", where alpha is the "learning rate", usually a small fraction like 0.001.   This has the effect of changing subsequent loss calculations to decrease.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mark.  And I perform these calculations per each training example, or for a set of training examples ? Thanks again !

Comment: There is the idea of "batching":   you divide all the training examples into groups of the same size (e.g., 16).   You do the calculation of the derivatives for all the examples in one batch, then update the variables based on the derivatives, and then move on to the next batch.    Working through all the batches like this comprises what's called one "epoch" and typically, you will repeat all the calculations for the remaining epochs, each time getting closer (hopefully) to the solution.

Comment: Aha ! I see ! in other words : for the first batch, I do initialize the array of weights with random numbers, I do perform the 1st forward and the 1st backward propagation, and the updated weights at the end of 1st back-propagation become the non-random weights in the 2nd forward-propagation, correct ? much appreciated !